# WordPress Database Error - Table 'sq_subscription' Already Exists

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress with PHP 5.3.

In the error log, I'm now getting this error:

```
WordPress database error Table 'sq_subscription' already exists for query CREATE TABLE sq_subscription (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subs_prdct_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    subs_order_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subs_prdct_price varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subs_prdct_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    merchant_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    apikey varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    currency varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    hashvalue varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    token varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subs_total_price varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subs_interval varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    time_perioud varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    subs_length varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    start_data varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    expiry_date varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) made by require('C:\Webs\site.com\www\wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('C:\Webs\site.com\www\wp-includes\template-loader.php'), include('C:\Webs\site.com\www\wp-content\themes\gk-portfolio\woocommerce.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('C:\Webs\site.com\www\wp-content\themes\gk-portfolio\header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), call_user_func_array, addtable
```

I've tried deleting that table (sq_subscription) but it just keeps giving this error. I'm not sure what else do to.

If it helps, there is also a mistake in the email WooCommerce now generates:
[image]

It's almost as if it thinks the items being bought are on a subscription basis, when they are actually not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just find where `CREATE TABLE sq_subscription` is being executed and change it to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sq_subscription`.

Your WooCommerce issue may be occurring because of this, but it's too broad and there's not enough information to go on.

Comment: If I may, what additional information may help with your assessment outcome? I'll do a search now for `CREATE TABLE sq_subscription` anyhow and replace it to see if that helps.

Comment: Okay! That's now been fixed. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` solved everything. Even the PHP logs that were maxing out the servers HDD space because of that error has been solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: @t0rxe Sorry for the late reply - I'm glad that it helped you. If you wouldn't mind, please click the 'checkmark' under the vote score to the left of my question, and upvote it for visibility. Thanks!

Comment: I tried that before you even asked. I need a reputation however of 15 before I am allowed to do that (pretty annoying in my opinion). I just gave the rep system a read, and you need to up vote my first post to provide me with more rep. When I have enough rep, I'll be sure to come back and do it to you. Thanks.